# Handle "big" Recordset from Access in VBA, DoEvents

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, recordset

My goal is to calculate the phone cost for every call coming from our call-manager. The script works on small tables (<1k), but get stucked at the actual data.

***My call table has 160k rows.*** The q_get_called result 6 columns. The script works fine everytime till row 7431. I tried on smaller tables and it did his Job also. If I don't use DoEvents function Access won't respond anymore but Script also run only until around row 8000 after 30 minutes.

**General Question: Is there something important in vba, like Setting variables back to 0 after each Loop, to handle such data sizes?**

I already reduced the query to those 4 columns needed. Might be the Select Case Statement better? Or is there a better way to update the cost into the call_table, than my insertSQL-approach?

If I pause the script after several minutes, it got stuck at the DoEvents() function.

```
Set Datenbank = CurrentDb
Set rs_calls = Datenbank.OpenRecordset("q_get_called", dbOpenDynaset)
    'Loop through all call-data to calculate cost
    Do While Not rs_calls.EOF
    callID = rs_calls!globalCallID_CallId
    internal = rs_calls!IfInternal
    inside = rs_calls!FromInside
    If inside = 0 Or internal = -1 Then 'cost is Zero if call coming from outside or is internal
        cost = 0
    Else 'else proceed calculation
        callingNr = rs_calls!callingPartyNumber
        calledNr = rs_calls!finalCalledPartyNumber
        duration = rs_calls!duration

        If Left(calledNr, 3) Like "0??" Then 'domestic
            multiplier = 1
        ElseIf Left(calledNr, 3) Like "00?" Then multiplier = 5 'national
        ElseIf Left(calledNr, 3) Like "000" Then multiplier = 10 'international
        Else: multiplier = 0
        End If
        'Select Case Left(calledNr, 3) 'Maybe Select case is smarter?
        '    Case "0??"
        '        multiplier = 1
        '    Case "00?"
        '        multiplier = 5
        '    Case "000"
        '        multiplier = 10
        '    Case Else
        '        multiplier = 0
        'End Select
        cost = (duration / 60) * multiplier  
    End If
    insertSQL = "UPDATE tbl_cdr SET cost = " & cost & " WHERE globalCallID_callID = " & callID
    Datenbank.Execute (insertSQL) 'set cost column
    rs_calls.MoveNext
    subForm = DoEvents() 'pass control to OS
Loop
```

Comment: Couple of small things you could try with your code - using WITH rs_calls block and creating a parameter Update query but I think your best bet would be look into transactions - doing 2000-3000 at a time. That being said I would find it useful if you could copy/paste you SQL for your recordset query `q_get_called`. I think your update is basic enough it might be done via one query - but I have no idea how your query is related to your `tbl_cdr` table.

Comment: Also - what are you trying to accomplish by `If Left(calledNr, 3) Like "0??"` - that clause will result in true for your national and international numbers - so all numbers will be treated as domestic. Your case statement says they have to be equal to "0??", and so on. Is that what you're intending instead of `Like` and the `any character wildcard`, "?"

Comment: Go on! Make the leap! Have a crack at migrating this into something like SQL Server express (free). You can still use Access on the front end but you can use T-SQL to replace this VBA. If you expect your record counts to increase over time, you really need to move this on to a more scalable platform. You can even experiment with a free Azure cloud subscription then you don't have to install anything

Comment: @dbmitch I will have a look at Transactions and the WITH block, My `q_get_called` is a simple `Select ... From tbl_cdr` ,
I did a Major mistake with that if clause I realise now also :o
@Nick.McDermaid I already expected this advice. The record Count will not increase heavilly in the future. And for now I Need to build up a quick solution. If I'll get ressources for this Project again I will defnitely Setup a SQL Server.

Comment: If you can explain your if clause intentions we can build an update query and you won't need transactions. What does your data look like for the three types of numbers?

Comment: @dbmitch the `calledNr` is a string with maximum 14 characters, it can start with "b","+","0","00","000" or any other number. For the calculation only the "0;00;000" cases are relevant. Only set the `multiplier` to the related value "1;5;10" if it is one of those cases.

Comment: Try using `Like "0[!0][!0]"` for first if, `Like "00[!0]"` for second if, and `Like "000" for last if

Comment: Or simply reverse the order. First check for `000`, then for `00?`, then for `0??`. --- But this can most certainly be done in a single update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as solution doing everything directly in access with an update-query works fine for now.

```
UPDATE tbl_cdr SET tbl_cdr.cost = IIf(Left([tbl_cdr].[calledNumber],3)="000",
([tbl_cdr].[duration]/60)*10, IIf(Left([tbl_cdr].[calledNumber],2)="00",
([tbl_cdr].[duration]/60)*5, IIf (Left([tbl_cdr].[calledNumber],1)="0",
[tbl_cdr].[duration]/60,0)));
```

That worked out in <1min.
My calculation will get more complicated though. Like seperating the calls also by the `callingNumber`, and use different Multiplier constants according to them.

**Edit:
I implemented a little bit more logic now and struggling to do everything in one SQL Update Statement**

Is it possible to enter subqueries to the update Statement like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_cdr SET [tbl_cdr].[cost]=
 IIf([tbl_cdr].[fromInside]=-1,
  IIf(Left([tbl_cdr].[fncpn],3)="000",
   ([tbl_cdr].[duration]/60)*
   (SELECT international FROM [tbl_cc] WHERE ccc=Left(cpn,4);),
   IIf(Left([tbl_cdr].[fncpn],2)="00",
    ([tbl_cdr].[duration]/60)*
    (SELECT national FROM [tbl_cost] WHERE ccc=Left(cpn,4);),
     IIf(Left([tbl_cdr].[fncpn],1)="0",
     ([tbl_cdr].[duration]/60)*
     (SELECT domestic FROM [tbl_cost] WHERE ccc=Left(cpn,4);),
     0)
   )
  )
 ,0)
;`
```

**ErrorLog: "Operation must use an updateable query"**

-I do have all permissions on the Folder

-the linked tables contain Primary keys

Or is it just not the right way to mix this `IIf-clauses` with SQL?

As solution might work to have a query for each different `callingCountry`

Like this:

`UPDATE tbl_cdr AS cdr
SET cdr.cost = cdr.duration*
    (SELECT cc.international 
    FROM tbl_costConstant AS cc
    WHERE cc.callingCountryCode = 1760)
WHERE cdr.finalCalledPartyNumber Like "000%" AND cdr.callingPartyNumber Like "1760%";`

This seems like a big workaround though.

Comment: Please ask the new question as a new question. :) But for a start, replace the SELECT statements with `DLookup` calls.

Comment: *thumbs up* `Dlookup` worked perfectly. Thanks @Andre